# Does docx4j support the new Word 2013 Repeating section content control

Tags: ms-word, docx4j

I know that Docx4j supported repeating content in Content Controls in Word already before Microsoft did. (With the help of OpenDoPE and it's Word Add-In).

However, starting with Word 2013, the Repeating section content control is built-in. I cannot find wether Docx4j will evaluate this new content control correctly. Does anyone know? Or should I just try?

Thanks,

Christiaan

Answer (score 0):

docx4j 2.8.1 won't evaluate it, and nor does the current source code on GitHub.

Worse, docx4j 2.8.1 will drop that element during JAXB unmarshalling, consistent with the Ignorable attribute, since http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml is not included in the JAXB content.

GitHub master (from 11 July 2013) will retain this element (and other important Word 2010 & 2013 extensions), as will docx4j 3.0, when released.

Comment: I added the [issue](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/54) as requested. I look forward to any enhancements on this. Thank you.